# Make Jquery function wait for animation to finish

Tags: jquery, animation, promise

I know this has been asked a lot but I still can't seem to find an answer. I have two separate divs in my header and when one is clicked, it has some content fadeIn in the main part of my page. I'm trying to make it so that if one is already clicked, the new one has to wait for the old one to fadeOut before it fades in. My problem is that its not waiting for the old one to fadeOut, it's fading in right away. I left out the functions for page_2 but they're identical, just with the appropriate identifiers and variables switched.

```
var about_me_clicked = false;
var page_2_clicked = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#About_me').click(about_me_clicked_func);
$('#Page_2').click(page_2_clicked_func);

var about_me_clicked_func = function() {  
  if(page_2_clicked){
      $.when(toggle_page_2()).done(toggle_about_me());
      page_2_clicked = !page_2_clicked;
  }
  else toggle_about_me();
  about_me_clicked = !about_me_clicked;
}

var toggle_about_me = function() {
  //do some formatting....
  if (!about_me_clicked) {
      return $('#About_me_main').fadeIn('slow').promise();
  }
  else return $('#About_me_main').fadeOut('slow').promise();
```

I tried using just .done() without the $.when() but that didn't work either. I also tried using a callback/complete function for fadeIn/fadeOut but I can't do that because there's a case where neither have been clicked (when the page first loads) so I wouldn't be able to pass in another function. Any help will be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: can you use setInterval js function to do this synchronization?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I would like to use a method that doesn't rely on waiting for a set amount of time because if I want to edit the animation time I'd have to change that, and I feel like that's not the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: i idea is to keep a variable that is set to true when first animation is started. when 2nd div is click, it will check if the variable is set to true. if it is, then it will call setInterval to check if the animation is finished after an interval. once first animation is finished, the timer needs to be cleared using clearInterval and call second animation. I am not sure if this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether if an element is currently being animated:

```
if($('#About_me_main').is(':animated'))
```

or simply `stop()` any ongoing animations and clear the queue:

```
$('#About_me_main').stop(true).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy way of use function callbacks.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/L76yL/1/)**

Look let me explain you. With function like fadeOut and fadeIn, you can use callbacks like this:

```
$(function () {
        $('.btn').on('click', function () {
            $('.one').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('.two').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
```

So once fadeOut is completed, it triggers fadeIn().

Comment: I'm aware that function callbacks would be enormously useful here, but as I mentioned in the question I'm unable to because there will be some cases in 'toggle_about_me' where there will be no callback (the case where neither is clicked).